# SyntaxError in Pins#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep Getting SyntaxError in Pins#index which points to this code

```
<%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure of the problem because i have checked the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/gotva/592d2bdf22229c400d1f)
You missed one `<% end %>` which closes internal if-statement.

PS you should post view code in the question - in this way you would have got much faster responce from the community.

Comment: <h1>listings</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>User_id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pin.description %></td>
        <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>